# How to restrict an ad hoc variable filter to a specific panel in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, monitoring, dashboard

User selects the option to filter from data listed in a panel, and that panel must not affected by the filter selected by the user, but Grafana variable ad hoc filter is applicable to the complete dashboard.
So, How to restrict an ad hoc variable filter to a specific panel in Grafana?

An option to limit the filter to particular panel in Grafana dashboard

Comment: Sounds like you don't need ad hoc filter at all. Just create textbox variable and use it as an additional selector in query like `my_metric{label1="value1",label2="value2"  $additional_filter}`, and value for said additional filter should be of the manner `, label3="value3"` or `, label3="value3", label4="value4"`